# How to manage incoming communication messages?

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

My application is listen the communication using UDP.
The packages that i receiving are Images.

I getting the same image twice.. when receiving first imageXX i need to wait for the second imageXX and than do some image analyzing on imageXX.

Each image has id and this id is int that can be from 0 to 199.
So i define array that save the imageXX state.

I must keep always on the order and i know that image number 8 can't change state to waiting and to analyzing state before image number 9.

I wrote this simple code

```
  const int ElementRange = 200;

  MessageElement[] _msgElem = new MessageElement[ElementRange] 

  // event listener 
  private void OnMsgWaitReceived(object sender, VideoFrame image)
  {
       lock(_locker)
       {
              _msgElem[image.id].ChangeState(WAITING);
       }
  }

  private void OnMsgAnalyzeReceived(object sender, VideoFrame image)
  {
        lock(_locker)
       {
              if(_msgElem[image.id].IsWaiting())
              {
                     // ERROR
              }
              else
              {
                  _msgElem[image.id].ChangeState(ANALYTE);
              }
       }
  }
```

But .. there are two problems that i see and i don't know how to handle with

1. once image8 is received and come to the 'OnMsgWaitReceived' method and now image9 afte it image10 is got to the 'OnMsgWaitReceived' also.
   The locker will keep them out of the update _msgElem ==> when the locker release it is possible that image10 will be update his state before image9 and this is wrong.
2. once image8 is received and come to the 'OnMsgWaitReceived' method and now image9 and image10 is got to the 'OnMsgWaitReceived' also => the locker will keep them out of the update _msgElem.

And now the second image9 is got to 'OnMsgAnalyzeReceived' but because of the locker on the 'OnMsgWaitReceived' the image9 waiting state is not appear and this is also wrong.

Using concurrentQueue is something i can do - but i not sure this is the best solution.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand: Is each image composed of two UDP packets that have to be analyzed together? Does image 8 have to be analyzed before image 9 and image 9 before image 10? Do you realize that with UDP protocol, the order of the packets on the receiving side is not guaranteed to be the same as the order in which they were sent?

Comment: no no ... image8 can't be analyze on the first time i get it .. i need to get the second time image8 to make the analyze.

yes, i get first image8 from UDP 1 ( port X1 ) and the second image8 from UDP 2 ( port X2 ). 

There is not possible option that i will get from the network layer the second image8 before i got the first image 8